# ag-Grid - Is it possible to create a floating menu for each row?

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to create a menu that appears when a user hovers on a row, just like in the image below.
[image]

I did not find any built-in option to achieve this. Also tried using a custom CellRenderer function to create an element that I could move around later, but that didn't work as expected since it presented some other challenges (css wise) and was not really achieving the goal.

Is there a way to build this kind of menus in ag-Grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work around the problem, you could use onCellMouseOver & onCellMouseOut methods:

```
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    onCellMouseOver : onCellMouseOver,
    onCellMouseOut:   onCellMouseOut,
    ...
};
```

Define both functions:

```
var onCellMouseOver = function(event){
    //Get current row
    var rowIndex = event.node.rowIndex;
    var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);

    //Set current row as not selected - in order to base on 'cellStyle' function
    row.setSelected(true);

    //Setup refresh params
    var params = {
        force: true, //Force refresh as cell value didn't change
        rowNodes: [row]
    };

    //Refresh current row cells
    gridOptions.api.refreshCells(params);
}
```

```
var onCellMouseOut = function(event){
    //Get current row
    var rowIndex = event.node.rowIndex;
    var row = gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);

    //Set current row as not selected - in order to base on 'cellStyle' function
    row.setSelected(false);


    //Setup refresh params
    var params = {
        force: true, //Force refresh as cell value didn't change
        rowNodes: [row]
    };
```

Then define 'cellStyle' function for your column:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "your_column_name", field: "your_column",
       cellStyle: function(params) {;
       console.log('Is row selected', params.node.selected);
            if (params.node.selected) {
                return {display : 'none'};
            } else {
                return {display : 'inherit'};
            }
        }
    }
];
```

You can find more about data refresh here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

The full implementation of the code above might be found here: [Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-gridshowhiderowelement-rc6he?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

> Second solution, edited after comments:

Another way is to use css classes to achieve the result.

```
   {
      headerName: "Price",
      field: "price",
      cellStyle: { "text-align": "center" },
      cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return (
          "<div class='buttons'>" +
          "<div class='back'>" +
          params.value +
          "</div>" +
          "<div class='front'><button>Option A</button><button>Option B</button></div>" +
          "</div>"
        );
      }
```

Buttons are shown on hover based on `.ag-row-hover` ag-grid class:

```
.front {
  display: none;
}
.ag-row-hover .front {
  display: inherit;
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-gridshowhiderowelement-c1l1o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thanks Kamil. That looks really similar to what I need, but not quite though. The buttons need not to be on an specific column. Or to put it differently, there won't be an Actions column, the buttons should appear on top of the actual cell content (for instance, on top of the Price column).

Comment: When you will place the action buttons outside the row, you won't be able to take advantage of 'on hover' event. Is that you want?

Comment: No, actually it's similar to what you showed before, but the buttons won't be inside a column, just floating over the row (there won't be a column whose only purpose is holding the buttons).

Comment: @cfr - please try 'Second solution, edited after comments' should work for you - please give a feedback if this silved the issue.

Comment: Excelent! that's exactly what I needed!